# How To parse extract the values present in XML node description in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am able to parse and extract the inner text within xml tags. I am not able to extract the values present in Job tag
 My Xml file format

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <SmPpProperties>
     <SmProperties>
       <Job Name="Job001" CreatedDate="2012-10-15T10:43:56.0972966-06:00" ModifiedDate="2012-10-       15T10:46:07.6878231-06:00">
 //            **I am not able to extract the values present in above Job tag**
         <NuclearSystem>Barium</NuclearSystem>
                      </Job>
    </SmProperties>
 <SmPpProperties>
```

C# code

```
       // Load XML Document
             XmlDocument MyDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
       // Select Node     
       MyDoc.Load(@"C:\Users\SRangarajan\Desktop\12001_.xml");

            XmlNode MyNode = MyDoc.SelectSingleNode("SmPpProperties/SmProperties/Job");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("NuclearSystem: ", MyNode.InnerText));
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

[XmlNode.InnerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns concatenated *value* of node and its child notes. That will give you `Barium`. Name, ModifiedDate and CreatedDate are attributes.

Your intent is not clear, but If you want to get concatenated values of all attributes:

```
String.Join(",", MyNode.Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>().Select(a => a.Value))
```

Or you can get value of particular attribute by name or index:

```
string name = MyNode.Attributes["Name"].Value;
string createdDate = MyNode.Attributes[1].Value;
```

**NOTE:** I always suggest you use Linq to Xml for parsing xml. You can easily create strongly typed object from xml:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\SRangarajan\Desktop\12001_.xml");
XElement j = xdoc.Root.Element("SmProperties").Element("Job");
var job = new {
                Name = (string)j.Attribute("Name"),
                CreatedDate = (DateTime)j.Attribute("CreatedDate"),
                ModifiedDate = (DateTime)j.Attribute("ModifiedDate"),
                NuclearSystem = (string)j.Element("NuclearSystem")
            };
```

That give you job object, which will have strongly-typed properties for name, created date and modified date. And date properties will have `DateTime` type!

[image]

Comment: @ Sergey : Thanks for your swift reply should i try like this ?  string Job = node.Attributes[3].Value;

Comment: @ShrivatsanRangarajan yes, you should use `XmlNode.Attributes` property. You can get attribute by index, by name, or you can get them all as I shown in my answer. And yes, `XmlAttrubute` has value property which returns its value

Comment: @ Sergey : Thumbs up for ur alternative solution. Thanks a lot. Also i need to handle datatype conversion fr these attributes inorder to insert into my sql database table

Comment: @ShrivatsanRangarajan sorry, didn't get you. What datatype conversion?

Comment: My Sql Table schema -CREATE TABLE CAMPAIGNS( Nuclear_System CHAR(20))   need to insert the extracted data barium into this table . connection string i can establish...how about the DB datatype input

Comment: @ShrivatsanRangarajan sorry, still don't understand you. Now it's not clear why you need attributes values, if you have only Nuclear_System column

Comment: I have many columns in my schema. Just for quick question i typed it. i will follow ur comments thanks a lot @ Sergey

Answer (score 0):

try to use linq , like this:

```
string xml = "xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    XElement nuclear = xdoc.Descendants(document.Root.Name.Namespace + "NuclearSystem").FirstOrDefault();

    string nuclearSystem = nuclear.Value();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the Attributes, use the Attributes property and then access the Value:

```
XmlNode MyNode = MyDoc.SelectSingleNode("SmPpProperties/SmProperties/Job");
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Name: ", MyNode.Attributes["Name"].Value));
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("CreatedDate: ", MyNode.Attributes["CreatedDate"].Value));
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("ModifiedDate: ", MyNode.Attributes["ModifiedDate"].Value));
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("NuclearSystem: ", MyNode.InnerText));
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks a lot. i was about to ask a question on this. Thanks for your reply.